# Migrate Windows Server 2003 to 2008 & Data Loss

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if I migrate from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 (x64) do I have to reinstall all applications in new Operating System or I will be able to simply upgrade the OS without any data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [**this MS Technet Forum thread**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverMigration/thread/dab33e51-25f4-476c-b173-7e65ee253373).

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2003 R2 can both be upgraded in-place to Windows Server 2008, as long as you keep the following in mind:
>
> - The Windows Server 2003 patchlevel should be at least Service Pack 1
> - You can't upgrade across architectures (x86, x64 & Itanium)
> - Standard Edition can be upgraded to both Standard and Enterprise Edition
>
>   - Enterprise Edition can be upgraded to Enterprise Edition only
>   - Datacenter Edition can be upgraded to Datacenter Edition only
>
> This might be your preferred option when:
>
> - Your Active Directory Domain Controllers can still last three to five years  economically and technically)
> - You worked hard to get your Active Directory in the shape it's in.
> - Your servers are in tip-top shape.